# About Geometry and Energy calculations in castep

Tags: castep

I am doing energy calculations for the graphene structure in CASTEP code. The structure consists of 30 atoms. I want to find out its band structure and density of state.

When I run the calculations, after up to 60 or 70 iterations, it cannot respond. Sometimes the job fails, but most of the time, in 60 or 70 iterations, it does not go further. I waited for it for a long time, but still it did not go further, so I stopped the job by myself.

I don't know what to do. Should I first do geometry optimization without checking the band structure and density of state and then do energy optimization? But in energy, then I have to check the band structure and density of state because I have seen somewhere that first you have to do geometry optimization and then do energy optimization by checking band structure and density of state.

I am doing collinear spin polarization. One more thing: should I uncheck, fix occupancy, and optimize the total cell? By default, it is already checked.

Please, anyone, suggest something about this. I need help in this regard.[image]

Comment: When you said "energy optimization" what do you mean? The geometry optimization is done changing the system geometry until the energy convergence criterion is reached.

Comment: Are you sure your unit cell is correct? Are you studying some sort of vdW structures? And your structure does not seem to be of graphene.

Comment: Hello camps and hemanth please help me in this regard. As in the task section I used energy. I am not doing geometry optimization. My teacher told me that you can find out the band gap and density of state with this also. The teacher said that you can find the bandgap and density of state with both whether you want to do geometry optimization or using enrgy in the task section. And hemanth this structure was given to me by my teacher she said that it is graphene. I have checked its symmetry it consists of carbon atoms.

Comment: Camps and hemanth I used GGA and also used LDA but still it stop in the middle. Sometimes the job failed but moast of the time the iterations doesn't move forward from about 80 to 90. I am doing these on my laptop which 4th generation and 8 GB of ram. Is it the problem of my laptop?

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: @Sha I have 8 GB ram

Comment: @Camps Hello, please help me in this regard. As in the task section, I used energy. I am not doing geometry optimization. My teacher told me that you can find out the band gap and density of state with this also. The teacher said that you can find the bandgap and density of state with both, whether you want to do geometry optimization or use energy in the task section.

Comment: @HemanthHaridas Hello, this structure was given to me by my teacher; she said that it is graphene. I have checked its symmetry; it consists of carbon atoms.

Comment: @Camps I used GGA and also used LDA, but still it stopped in the middle. Sometimes the job fails, but most of the time the iterations don't move forward from about 80 to 90. I am doing these on my laptop, which is 4th generation and has 8 GB of RAM. Is it a problem with my laptop?

Comment: @HemanthHaridas I used GGA and also used LDA, but still it stopped in the middle. Sometimes the job fails, but most of the time the iterations don't move forward from about 80 to 90. I am doing these on my laptop, which is 4th generation and has 8 GB of RAM. Is it a problem with my laptop?

Comment: Just by looking at the image that you have posted along with the question, I genuinely doubt if the structure is periodic in the x-direction. There is just too much space between the two periodic images (unless i am missing something). Please check that.

Comment: @AusafAli 1) Although you should always relax (geometry optimization) your structure for any reasonable calculation, you nevertheless can compute band structure and density of states (for the sake of comparision, for example) without geometry optimization. 2) 8GB of RAM is not the perfect (actually it is very small, especially for a 30 atoms calculation) choice for a DFT calculation. 3) Based on the attached screenshot, your structure does not look normal. 4) To be able to find the exact cause of your problem please attach the .castep output file

Comment: @Sha I think its impossible to upload a file here. I have tried it; if you know the way, then please tell me. Band structure and density of states can be found without geometry optimization as well by selecting only energy in the task section. I have tried it with some other structures.

Comment: @HemanthHaridas What do you mean by periodic in the x direction? I don't understand. I also removed some atoms from the structure, reducing it to 18 atoms, but still, it created the problem.

Comment: If you need to calculate the properties of a material, it is understood that the structure has some sort of periodicity. In your case, if you replicate the structure along x-direction it will not have bonds across the images

Comment: @AusafAli there are many free upload websites, share the download link here

Comment: @Sha Could you please tell me the names of some free upload websites? I have tried to find some but couldn't find any.  I also uploaded the file to MetaStack Exchange.  If you saw that, then please tell me about it.

Comment: @HemanthHaridas How to replicate the structure along the x-direction. Could you please guide me, as I am a beginner to using castep? So its difficult for me.

Comment: @Sha I have uploaded the file to MetaStack Exchange, but the community members have removed the file. please tell me the names of the upload websites and how to use them.

Comment: @Sha https://www.filemail.com/d/uwazztpldlisvpo. This is the downloaded link to the filemail website.  Check if it work

Comment: @Sha where are you❓ you didn't answer

Comment: This is not graphene, this is a rather strange-looking aromatic molecule of some kind, with some highly reactive un-passivated carbon atoms at the edges. The simulation box is also enormous for so few atoms, and 8 GB RAM is probably not sufficient.

Comment: Could you paste your .cell and .param files at the end of the question, so we can see what's going wrong for ourselves?